# Convert JSON to XML in Java with different JSON object names

Tags: java, json, xml, jackson, format-conversion

I have this JSON string:

```
{
    "purpose": {
        "caption": "Purpose",
        "value": "Buy a goat"
    },
    "goatValue": {
        "caption": "Goat value",
        "value": "4500000"
    },
    "loanAmount": {
        "caption": "Loan amount",
        "value": "5000000"
    },
    "childrenInfo": [{
        "gender": {
            "caption": "Gender",
            "value": "Boy"
        },
        "provider": {
            "caption": "Provider",
            "value": "Yes"
        },
        "age": {
            "caption": "Age",
            "value": "5"
        }
    },
    {
        "gender": {
            "caption": "Gender",
            "value": "Girl"
        },
        "provider": {
            "caption": "Provider",
            "value": "No"
        },
        "age": {
            "caption": "Age",
            "value": "17"
        }
    }]
}
```

And I want to convert it to this xml structure:

```
<Row>
    <caption>Purpose</caption>
    <value>Buy a goat</value>
</Row>
<Row>
    <caption>Goat value</caption>
    <value>4500000</value>
</Row>
<Row>
    <caption>Loan amount</caption>
    <value>5000000</value>
</Row>
<Row>
    <caption>Gender</caption>
    <value>Boy</value>
</Row>
<Row>
    <caption>Provider</caption>
    <value>Yes</value>
</Row>
<Row>
    <caption>Age</caption>
    <value>5</value>
</Row>
<Row>
    <caption>Gender</caption>
    <value>Girl</value>
</Row>
<Row>
    <caption>Provider</caption>
    <value>No</value>
</Row>
<Row>
    <caption>Age</caption>
    <value>17</value>
</Row>
```

This is suppose to work with any JSON object name (in this case purpose, goatValue and loanAmount) because there is no way to know the names of the JSON objects. I've tried using Jackson ObjectMapper and mapped the JSON string to

```
HashMap<String, HashMap<String, String>>
```

, but now I don't know what to do.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You have an object like Data(Caption, Value) and with jackson you get a Map<String, Data> ?   Then if you add jaxb annotation on Data, you can write the list a <row> <caption>..</caption><value>...</value>...    Is this your question ?

Comment: Fixed my question.

Comment: You'd better create a class with String caption, String value, and get from JSON a map of <String, Data> then you can create from map.values() a Collection<Data> that can be serialized to XML with jaxb.

Comment: Ok, I've got a class Row with String caption, value. Do I use ObjectMapper readValue to map from JSON to Map<String, Row>? If that's the case, what is the second parameter suppose to be?         HashMap<String, Row> nestedMap = jsonMapper.readValue(jsonSchemaString, ?);

Comment: you need to use a type like :   TypeReference<HashMap<String,Row>> type  = new TypeReference<HashMap<String,Row>>() {};

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to read the JSON as a `Map<String, Object>` and create a `Row` object consisting of a caption and value field. After that you need to iterate over the entries in the map distinguishing between maps and lists of maps. In the case of maps, these need to be converted to Row objects and added to a collection of row objects. In the case of the lists of maps, the same thing needs to be done in an inner loop. When the iteration is done, the rows need to be added to a wrapper object which can then be converted to xml using an XmlMapper.

I've created a gist that works on your example:
https://gist.github.com/santmatthew/8f85399ad86fb45fec0be0c5df1a9825

Comment: Nice! Is there a way to specify the parent <row> as <table>?

Comment: And do you know what to do if the JSON includes an array such as: 
"childrenInfo": [{
            "gender": {
                "caption": "Gender",
                "value": "Boy"
            },
            "provider": {
                "caption": "Provider",
                "value": "Yes"
            },
            "age": {
                "caption": "Age",
                "value": "5"
            }
        },
}]

Comment: I'm not sure if you mean renaming row to table or renaming the root element to table. I'll give you an answer for both anyway. In case 1, all you need to do is to change the value in the JsonProperty annotation for getRow() to "Table" from "Row". If you want to change the root element name i.e. XmlWrapper in this case, you can either rename the class from XmlWrapper to Table or add the annotation @JacksonXmlRootElement(localName="Table") on the class declaration.

Comment: For the array case, you would need to give me a complete input and what you expect the output to look like as there are many possible interpretations.

Comment: Your code gives the output:
<XMLWrapper>
    <row>
        <row>
            <caption>Purpose</caption>
            <value>Buy a goat</value>
        </row>
        <row>
            <caption>Goat amount</caption>
            <value>500000</value>
        </row>
    </row>
</XMLWrapper>

I am taking about renaming the outer row.

Comment: In that case, you need to iterate over the collection and map accordingly:

This new gist should handle that scenario: https://gist.github.com/santmatthew/8f85399ad86fb45fec0be0c5df1a9825

Comment: I fixed it in the last revision.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks so much :)